# Azure pipeline unit test Uri for TestContext.DeploymentDirectory causes failure

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, mstest

I have an Azure DevOps build that is executing a suite of unit tests. The tests pass locally but the build fails on the Hosted 2017 agent because of a failed test that is using [TestContext.DeploymentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.deploymentdirectory?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).

The failing test creates a mock settings object using the `TestContext`. The `OutputPath` for the mock settings is set to the `TestContext.DeploymentDirectory` value. The mock settings object is then passed to a constructor and the resulting object checked with an `Assert.AreEqual` as shown;

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_DiskStorageManager()
{
  var settings = new MockDataHandlerSettings(TestContext);
  var manager = new DiskStorageManager(settings);

  Assert.AreEqual(settings.OutputPath, manager.OutputPath);
}
```

Within the constructor is the following;

```
if (Uri.TryCreate(settings.OutputPath, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri outputUri))
{
  OutputPath = outputUri.LocalPath;
  IsLocalOutput = outputUri.IsLoopback;
}
else
{
  throw new ArgumentException($"Output path is invalid {settings.OutputPath}");
}
```

The tests run fine locally but the following test failure occurs on the hosted agent;

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<D:\a_temp..\Tests\TestResults\TestResults\Deploy_VssAdministrator 2020-03-10 03_09_31\Out>. 
Actual:<D:\a\Tests\TestResults\TestResults\Deploy_VssAdministrator 2020-03-10 03_09_31\Out>.
```

What is causing the change from `D:\a_temp..\` to `D:\a\` and making the test fail?

**EDIT**

The testing task is defined by the following YAML;

```
variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'debug'
  BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'

steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*Tests.dll
     !**\obj\**
    runSettingsFile: '$/MyProject/Tests/.runsettings'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

The `.runsettings` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
        <ResultsDirectory>..\Tests\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
        <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
    </RunConfiguration>
  <DeploymentEnabled>True</DeploymentEnabled>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Could you share the setting of your test task in pipeline? Is the value for field `Test results folder` `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT The `Test results folder` is still the default value `$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults`, it's not present in the YAML task settings which I've now added along with the `.runsettings` used.

Comment: Thanks @LeviLu-MSFT for the suggestion, I'd not thought about what was really setting the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test fails because of the relative path in the [ResultsDirectory element of the .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#elements-of-a-runsettings-file). The tests intialize with;

```
TestResultsDirectory intialized to D:\a\_temp\..\Tests\TestResults\TestResults
```

Removing `<ResultsDirectory>..\Tests\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>`;

```
TestResultsDirectory intialized to d:\a\_temp\TestResults
```

***Note:*** The expected value displayed in the failed test has not correctly escaped the `\`. The displayed value is `D:\a_temp..\Tests` but the failed message in the task log is `D:\a\_temp\..\Tests`.

This does not explain why the relative path is fully resolved in VS2019 16.4 and not in the Azure pipeline.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12513#issue-579001169